# Express & splitting routes into separate files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express app that follows the standard Express 4 format. ie, dependencies at the top, then app config, then routes, and finally, listen.

I'm trying to seperate out my routes into categorised files (eg. routes/authentication.js) however the app isn't carrying through the dependencies so when I run `node app.js` the app breaks because the CLI says that passport isn't defined in routes/authentication.js, which it isn't, because it's defined at the top of app.js with all the other dependencies.

I guess my question is how can I go about 'sharing' the dependencies so I don't have to list them at the top of every file? This is how i'm requiring the separate files:

**app.js**

```
require('./app/routes/authentication')(app);
```

**routes/authentication.js**

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    [routes]
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with listing the dependencies in every route file? Require()'d modules are cached so it's not bad for your performance.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, I just wondered if there was an alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where a dependency module is really used often where you already have access to app, you can set the value on app, e.g. `app.config = require('./config')`. (*However*, where it is generally best to specify the dependencies for a particular module at the top of that module for the sake of clarity. There's no harm other than adding a bit more code for each module.)

Additionally, although it is fine to use a constructor function and passing in `app` to this function, you could also use modules for this purpose. Ensure you export `app` the moment you create it, i.e. `var app = module.exports = express();` and then just `var app = require('../app');` from other libraries. You'll see this in some of the Express examples.

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/expressjs/generator/tree/master/templates/js/routes if for an example using Express 4.